# sed: cannot rename ./sed6x9apB: Operation not permitted using docker-compose with WordPress image

Tags: docker, network-shares, virtualbox, sed, mv

WordPress container fails to start when using docker-compose, where there are existing WordPress files, aborting with the following error:

```
sed: cannot rename ./sedtpghTB: Operation not permitted
```

Error only occurs when WordPress files are hosted on a VirtualBox (vboxsf) shared folder.  Sharing the folder over SMB/CIFS avoids the error.

Setup:

- Host: Win 10 (64b)
- Guest: 3.16.0-4-amd64 (debian_version 8.6) Guest/Vbox version: 5.1.12 r112440 (Qt5.6.2)
- WordPress files are shared out using a VirtualBox shared folder mounted at `/media/vmhost`

Here is the output of docker-compose config:

```
        networks: {}
        services:
          db:
            environment:
              MYSQL_DATABASE: my_db_name
              MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'MY_ROOT_PASSWORD'
              MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'MY_ROOT_PASSWORD'
              MYSQL_USER: root
            image: mysql:5.7
            ports:
            - 3306:3306
            restart: never
            volumes:
            - db_data:/var/lib/mysql:rw
          wordpress:
            depends_on:
            - db
            environment:
              WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
              WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: my_db_name
              WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: 'MY_PASSWORD'
              WORDPRESS_DB_USER: root
            image: wordpress:latest
            ports:
            - 80:80
            restart: never
            volumes:
            - /media/vmhost/www/test:/var/www:rw
            - /media/vmhost/www/test/public_html:/var/www/html:rw
        version: '2.0'
        volumes:
          db_data: {}
          wp_data: {}
```

When I attempt a sed on the vboxsf share, I get a similar error, but only when the source file is readonly.

```
echo 'hello' > hello.txt
chmod a-w hello.txt
sed -i  's/hello/goodbye/' hello.txt
```

error:

```
sed: cannot rename ./sed6x9apB: Operation not permitted
```

output of mount | grep www

```
    www on /media/vmhost/www type vboxsf (rw,nodev,relatime)
```

When I use a CIFS share , mounted at /media/vmhost/www2 , everything works fine.

```
//my_laptop/www on /media/vmhost/www2 type cifs (rw,relatime,vers=1.0,sec=ntlm,cache=strict,username=vboxsf,uid=0,noforceuid,gid=0,noforcegid,addr=192.168.1.5,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,nounix,serverino,noperm,rsize=61440,wsize=65536,actimeo=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug with VirtualBox, see [Ticket #4890](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/4890) .

Per frank's reply:

> fixed for Linux hosts but not for Windows hosts. In contrast to Linux where a file can be removed if the directory is writable but the file itself is read-only, a read-only file cannot be removed on Windows

This impacts sed since sed makes a copy of the source file ( in this case wp-config-sample.php )  to a temporary file, and then attempts to make the replacements which windows won't support since the copy is also  readonly.

For some reason, a proper share using CIFs is not impacted.

**Workaround 1: Make the source file writeable and restart the container.**

`chmod a+w wp-config-sample.php
 docker-compose up`

**Workaround 2: Use a CIFS share.**

1. On your Windows machine, share out the directory containing your WordPress files using the Windows Advanced sharing properties of the directory.
2. On your VirtualBox VM, add the following to /etc/fstab

   ```
   //my_laptop/www  /media/vmhost/www  cifs  username=WINDOWS_USER,password=WINDOWS_USER_PASSWORD,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,iocharset=utf8,noperm,sec=ntlm  0  0
   ```
3. mount

   `mount -a`

Comment: I'm having this issue in a virtualbox VM running Ubuntu 20 under a Windows 10 host, however all the files are writeable (permission bits are are rwxrwxrwx)...